# define id an expression is a well-formed expression of statement logic

Tags: logic

I have to deteremine whether each of the following expressions is a well-formed expression of statement logic or not

```
(a) (r ∧ ¬r)
(b) q
(c) ¬( p) ∨ (q <-> p)
(d) ( p ∧ (q ∧ r) ∨ p)
(e) ∧ → pq
(f) ((r ∧ (q → p)) → r)
```

So my answers

```
(a) formula
(b) formula(any atomic statement is a wff
(c) not a formula (no parethesis around atomic statement)
(d) ? not a formula
(e) not a formula
(f) well-formed formula
```

I am not sure about (d). Perhaps somebody can explain it and check the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is right. D is not a formula.  $p\land (q \land r) \lor p$ can mean $(p\land (q \land r)) \lor p$ or $p\land( (q \land r) \lor p) $, which are two different things.